# Should all method hashes be found in a smart contract's opcodes?

Tags: solidity, evm, bytecode, opcode, deployed-bytecode

I have a compiled/deployed solidity smart contract for which I have encoded all the functions signatures. (4-byte hashes)

With the deployed bytecode, I have parsed the pushdata into an array for all 'PUSH4' opcodes.

Within that final set, there seems to be a method hash missing from one of the smart contract functions. This is also the only method hash that is missing from the whole hex string representation of the bytecode.

The missing method hash is 0x00879679. The method can still be called though, so its definitely there. And it's state changing, so called in tx.

Is this normal? Or could have something to do with optimization?

I was hoping to be able to build a list of any smart contract's method hashes, but with this failure in my first example, I am kind of losing hope lol.

The code is too large to post here, but can be found in the open issue:
https://github.com/acuarica/evm/issues/49

Comment: Does it find a match if you remove the leading zeros?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the compiler will include every selector in the bytecode. The optimizer could simplify the dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Ok maybe this is glaringly obvious to most, but I have very little experience with machine/assembly/evm...

I guess bc the method hash starts with '00' (2 zeros) that only 3 bytes are stored for the selector, and it actually is found in the opcodes as 'PUSH3'.

So the 3-byte selector '879679' was actually found in the deployed bytecode.

So if a hashed function selector had 4 leading zeros, would it be stored in a JUMP2? What is the probability of that I wonder.

Comment: The probability of 4 leading zeros is that two bytes, or 16 bits, are all zero. So it's 1/2^16 = 1/65536